# not detect text on image

Tags: c++, tesseract

The task is as follows:

1. Read the text from the picture and determine the 2D coordinates
2. Draw a bounding box around the text.

I'm trying an example from the off. site "tesseract" to detect text with a picture, I take the first picture created through "Paint", actually not a picture, but black text on a white background, everything is perfectly detected, both Russian and English characters. Next, I try to recognize characters from a random picture from the Internet:

[image]

With grief in half, he discovers something. But she misses a lot. I'm trying a screenshot from my favorite game:

[image]

He just doesn't see anything, nothing at all, not in Russian, not in English. I tried different image formats. As far as I understand, you need a different algorithm? Or am I using the Api incorrectly? Maybe you need to combine opencv and tesseract algorithms?

Sample code used this one:

```
Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
  tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
  api->Init(NULL, "eng");
  api->SetImage(image);
  api->Recognize(0);
  tesseract::ResultIterator* ri = api->GetIterator();
  tesseract::PageIteratorLevel level = tesseract::RIL_WORD;
  if (ri != 0) {
    do {
      const char* word = ri->GetUTF8Text(level);
      float conf = ri->Confidence(level);
      int x1, y1, x2, y2;
      ri->BoundingBox(level, &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);
      printf("word: '%s';  \tconf: %.2f; BoundingBox: %d,%d,%d,%d;\n",
               word, conf, x1, y1, x2, y2);
      delete[] word;
    } while (ri->Next(level));
  }
```

Comment: Did you read tesseract docs? How did you implement hints from it to your code?

Comment: @user898678 whaaaat's hints???